# Shortcode Extract from HTML with parameters, using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I Implement a Template shortcode in HTML/Javascript? - Is there any Plugin available?

Like I have HTML written

```
<div id="teamPeople"> 
<h3>Management Team: </h3>
[showTeam id="2,3,5"]

<h3>Marketing Team: </h3>
[showTeam id="2,3,5"]

</div>
```

-- Once the HTML loaded, I would like to parse the HTML and get those shortcode "showTeam" with id, and call ajax to call Team UI to generate and replace?

Any Help?

Comment: It's a weird way to do it like this. The `[showTeam id="2,3,5"]` will show up in the browser, and will only be replaced if the ajax call is finished. I you have many of them, it could take some time. If you have any influence on the outputted HTML, consider using a `data-attribute` for the `<h3>` tags and process them.

Answer (score -1):

The term `shortcode` and the syntax reminds of Wordpress. Is that the context? Wordpress does replace the shortcodes server-side normally, but you could [try to come up with something that fills out the shortcodes via ajax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108874/loading-shortcode-with-ajax). I did once, it's possible without general problems.

If that wordpress-guess is is wrong, are you bound to this square-brackets-`[`-syntax? otherwise you can choose [from a wide range of java script templating engines](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/) like [mustache.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache).

Comment: I am not talking about Wordpress, I am looking for Only HTML and jQuery, The term may similar to Wordpress shortcode.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to your now deleted version

```js
const range = (size, startAt = 0) => [...Array(size).keys()].map(i => i + startAt);

document.querySelectorAll("h3").forEach(head => {
  const parentNode = head.parentNode;
  const id = head.nextSibling.wholeText.match(/ (.*?)]/)[1];
  const placeHolder = document.createElement("span");
  parentNode.replaceChild(placeHolder,head.nextSibling)
  
  const [team, workerIds] = id.split(":");
  let [start,end] = workerIds.split("-");
  end = end || start;
  Array.from(range(+end-start+1,+start)).forEach(i => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add('team-${team}-i')
    div.dataset.id=`team-${team}-workerid-${i}`
    div.textContent = `team-${team}-workerid-${i}`;
    parentNode.insertBefore(div,placeHolder)
  }); 
  parentNode.removeChild(placeHolder)
})
```

```html
<h3>Management Team: </h3>
[showTeam 10:3]

<h3>Marketing Team: </h3>
[showTeam 30:5-7]
```